# QFont to qss stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

With a `QFontDialog` I get a `QFont` object as return value. I am using Qt stylesheets with widgets, so setting `myWidget->setFont(fontFromDialog)` does **not** seem to have any effect.

Can I translate a font object into a qss string representing the values of the font, similar to `font.toString()` used with the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the font straight from the dialog using getFont, i'd try this potentially, might have to alter some code.

```
myWidget.setFont(QFontDialog::getFont(0, myWidget.font()));
```

Also, have a look at the Qt documentation for this as it could potentially help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QFont aFont;
QString theStyleSheet = QString("font: 75 %1pt \"%2\"").arg(aFont.pointSize()).arg(aFont.family());
```